# Invalid property ... set to ... Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()

Tags: vue.js, gsap, vuejs3

In Vue3, if I try a `gsap` animation in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook, it works, but if I try it in the `onMounted` hook inside `setup`, I get these warnings:

```
Invalid property rotationY set to 45 Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()
Invalid property rotationX set to 45 Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()
```

---

My `setup`:

```js
setup() {
    const comments = ref(null);
    const test = function() {
        gsap.fromTo(
            comments,
            { rotationY: 45 },
            {
                rotationX: 45,
                ease: 'back.in(1)',
            },
            'mousein'
        );
    };

    onMounted(test);

    return { comments };
},
```

The Vue docs say `onMounted` inside `setup` is the same as `mounted()`, so how could I be getting different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `comments` is a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref), you have to use its `value` prop to access the template ref:

```js
const test = function() {
    gsap.fromTo(
        // BEFORE:
        // comments,

        // AFTER:
        comments.value,

        /*...*/
    );
};
```